# Flutter приложение для входа по QR

Tags: flutter, мобильные-приложения, qrcode, qr

Имеется самописное приложение на flutter. Суть в том, что оно генерирует QR код с данными пользователя для посещения мероприятий университета. Волонтеры сканят эти коды и данные улетают в таблицу. Вопрос в том, как обезопасить вход, в том смысле, чтоб друзья и ТД и тп не сканили чужие скриншоты и соответственно те, кого по факту нет не появлялись в таблице.

И хотелось бы понять, как такие приложения работают на больших мировых площадках, в инете информацию не нашел

UPD1: плюс можно дать аккаунт другу погонять, что тоже влияет на безопасность

Answer (score 0):

Раз у каждого студента есть приложения и у этого приложения есть доступ к данным студента тогда можно сделать QR(id) для мероприятия. И студенты которые пришли на мероприятия должны отсканировать в приложении QR и приложения отправляет на сервер данные студента и id мероприятия. И чтобы студенты не делились фоткой QR можно на QR добавить геолокацию. Тогда получитсья нужно данным которые отправляются с приложения добавить геолокацию смартфона и геолокацию полученные с QR. в сервере сравнить локации в радиусе там например 100 метров и добавить в базу если смартфон не в этом радиусе значить QR был отсканирован извне. Ну типа так можно сделать

Answer (score 0):

Создайте сервер, который будет генерить TOTP . добавьте этот код в qr и по нему верефицируйте что этот код не фотка кода. От передачи аккаунта это не спасёт